# When to report the check for linear regression assumptions?

Tags: regression, assumptions

Here's the steps for an analysis.

- I know there is some past research implying there is a linear relationship between $Y$ and $X_1, \cdots, X_n$
- So I set a hypothesis that $Y$ is a linear function of $X_1, \cdots, X_n$.
- I get the dataset from the researchers.
- Given the data, using multiple linear regression model, I can calculate $R^2$ and coefficients with $p$-values for each of them.

If the model fit gives me the significant result, then I can conclude that my model is valid.

---

Say my boss insists me to test if the assumptions for the linear regression are met. So I have checked linearity/normality of residuals, equivariance/independence of variance.

Say some of the results of the check have failed to support the assumptions.

Here's my questions :

Should I report the results of the check **AFTER** the results of linear regression, or **BEFORE** the results of linear regression?

- Reason for **BEFORE** : if assumptions are not met, there is no sufficient evidence that my dataset is valid for linear regression. So as a prerequisite for the model building and proper conclusion, I do the check before the actual analysis.
- Reason for **AFTER** : the reason why I decided to build the model is that I have some past research implying that there is the linear relationship. Moreover, my hypothesis was not like "are the assumptions met?" So I do the actual analysis first, and as additional information about my model's validity, I can report the results of the assumption check later.

Comment: The assumptions all lie in the residuals. You need to fit a model before you can check the assumptions, so I would assume you report after you've fitted the model. You could say *given* my assumptions, my model is xxx, and as you can see, these assumptions are also met. If they're not met, well, I guess you've got to try and fix the model. (But i totally get that in reality there's nothing you can do sometimes)